# Lucene Tokenizer - Include Spaces

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

We have an application that tokenises certain data. The problem I have is that I have a comma delimited field I need to tokenize but not on spaces.  For Example:

```
"Age 6, Age 7, Age 8"
```

Becomes

```
Age
6
Age
7
Age
8
```

I need

```
Age 6
Age 7
Age 8
```

Is there a way for me to change the default behaviour on certain fields only?

The config setting I have at present:

```
<field fieldName="SizeGroup" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" 
boost="1f" type="System.String" 
settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, 
Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

Comment: You will need to specify the analyzer on your field: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/understanding-analyzers-and-sitecore-7  and might need to write a custom analyzer/tokenizer..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know C#, but I know Lucene. So for needed behavior you need to use [PatternAnalyzer](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d27/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_miscellaneous_1_1_pattern_analyzer.html), which allows you to specify a regexp, that will be used for tokenizing. In your case, pattern like `\\,` should work for splitting on commas.